# Read and display in richtext the next line in a text document by clicking a button using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, button, streamreader, notepad

I have these list in notepad 1-5 with names

1. Arman
2. Betty
3. Charlie
4. Delson
5. Ezra

Situation: when i click the button the name will appear in the richtext one by one until the end of the number. I have this codes yet It's not yet working.

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string file_name = "\\test1.txt";
        file_name = textBox1.Text + file_name; //textBox1.Text is my path

        int counter = 0;
        string line = "";

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(file_name);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = (line);
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();

        // Suspend the screen.
        richTextBox2.Text = line; //I use richtext for displaying the output
    }
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I'm still searching the correct array. I always search the readtoend and readline and I can't trigger it by button. nothing happend.

Comment: You cannot just write down an assignment and expect someone to do it for you. This is not how SO works. If you need help please provide some code sample for what have you done so far and ask question.

Comment: pardon. I already edit my question sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("yourPath"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = line;
                    this.Refresh();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit 1:
Sorry I made for textbox. Check this;

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("yourPath"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += line + "\n";
                this.Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks B.Yaylaci! It works.. yet I will ask how to show it by clicking once then the first line will show then next click the next line will show and so on.

Comment: @ChaRlie I Updated the answer.

Comment: yup2 Thanks. I also found it out. haha. Thanks! Great help!

yet I will ask how to show it by triggering every line per click on button?

Comment: @ChaRlie Too many easy requests :). You can do it. Put all the strings into array in the while loop. By using for loop you will check the current text's index (lets say 1), and you need the next name so basically you need to get array[index +1] and set it to textbox like this. `textbox.text = array[index +1];`

Comment: Thank you very much!. sorry for the easy request. Just a newbie :)
Soon I'm gonna love this programming. I hope i can thumbs up ur answer. yet i need 15 reputation. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify if you are writing this application for WPF or WinForms I will assume you are using WPF's RichTextbox. Here is an example:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("SampleInput.txt"))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        rbResult.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(line)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using WinForms that's why i have button and richtextbox. Do u also have an example for WinForm bro? It might be a great help